# Mysql Multiple Subquery Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
playlistid 
trackname 
playstatus
likes
dislikes
created
```

playstatus can have the following values:`0, 1, 2 and 4`.

The sql query that Im using now is:

```
 SELECT * from playlist
 WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=0
 ORDER BY (likes-dislikes) DESC, created ASC
```

Its worth to mention that there at all times only will be one row with playstatus = 1, one row with playlistid=3, but there will be multiple rows with playstatus = 0 and 2.

I want to change the query above so that I get 1 row from where playstatus=3, 1 row from where playstatus=1, and 3 rows from where playstatus=0 in one single query. All these have to be chosen based on the same orderby that you see in the query above.

All help is appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=1
ORDER BY (likes-dislikes) DESC, created ASC limit 1
union 
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=3 
ORDER BY (likes-dislikes) DESC, created ASC limit 1
union 
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=0
ORDER BY (likes-dislikes) DESC, created ASC limit 3
```

Comment: You forgot some parentheses, but other than that It worked like a charm. Since the other user didnt read the question correctly like you did, you get the V. (I needed to limit each playstatus, aswell as use orderby on each of them).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=3
union 
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=1
union 
SELECT * from playlist WHERE playlistid=$myplaylistid && playstatus=0
ORDER BY (likes-dislikes) DESC, created ASC
```